# Not found package error: package com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to Java SDK for Amazon AWS. I have an existing working codebase. I am implementing AWS STS based client id & secret lookup, but getting a package not found

```
error: package com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager does not exist.
```

which I am not able to locate the cause of, do I need to install some external package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood what you trying to do.
But in my case, I added the following maven dependency to the pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Or if you don't use maven then go to this page https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/aws-sdk-java/2.19.17 and download the jar file manually.
After that you can use these import statements:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.SecretsManagerClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.GetSecretValueRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.GetSecretValueResponse;
```

Now you should be able to access your aws secret manager.
Is this the answer to your question?